# Add function in variables in while loop

Tags: bash, sed, variable

I am writing script to run a software. I am trying to add function in while loops to trim text in variable, so that it can be applied as variable in other part of the command. But what should be the correct way to add the function?

This is a working code when only one `--msa` file is run.

```
while read -r i; do 
    raxml-ng --msa ../C049.laln_1l --model $i --prefix C049-rT; 
done < ../C049.model
```

For a very brief introduction, raxml-ng is the software I use, the parameters to run the software is set up by each of these `--msa`, `--model`, and `--prefix` files. For every `--msa` file, they have their corresponding `--model` and `--prefix`. I named them the same to ease the scripting. For eg., `C049.laln_1l` need to be matched with `C049.model` and `C049-rT`.

As in the example above, I can loop the command if I have other `--msa` files with the same extension like this:

```
while read -r i; do 
    while read -r j; do
        raxml-ng --msa ../$i.laln_1l --model $j --prefix $i-rT; 
    done < ../$i.model
done < msalist
```

Now I have a list of `--msa` files (listed in `msalist`) to run and some of them with different file extension.

The `msalist` file contains:

```
C049.laln_1l
C092.laln_1l
C016.laln_1l
gc30_part.cseq
gc3f.glist.cseq...
```

I named the `model` and `prefix` using only the text before the first `.` .

Eg. list for `model` parameter:

```
C049.model
C092.model
C016.model
gc30_part.model
gc3f.model...
```

It is the same case for `prefix` parameter.

So when writing the bash script to loop for all the `--msa` files in `msalist`, I tried do `"$( sed 's/\..*//g' "$i" )".model` to get `C049.model` instead of `C049.laln_1l.model`. But it doesn't seem to work.

```
trees=$2
threads=$3

while read -r i; do
        while read -r j; do
                raxml-ng --msa ../"$i" --model "$j" --prefix "$( sed 's/\..*//g' "$i" )"-rT;
        done < ../"$( sed 's/\..*//g' "$i" )".model;
done < "$alnlist"
```

How to trim the text in `msalist` in order to be read by `--model` and `--prefix`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get the part before the first `.` in any POSIX shells, you can just do `${var%%.*}`. So here:

```
while IFS= read -r i; do
  prefix=${i%%.*}
  while IFS= read -r j; do
    raxml-ng --msa ../"$i" --model "$j" --prefix "$prefix-rT";
  done < "../$prefix.model";
done < "$alnlist
```

Also note the syntax to read a line is `IFS= read -r line`, not `read -r line`.

Here, you could also do:

```
while IFS=. read -r prefix rest; do
  while IFS= read -r j; do
    raxml-ng --msa ../"$prefix.$rest" --model "$j" --prefix "$prefix-rT";
  done < "../$prefix.model";
done < "$alnlist
```

If you wanted to use `sed` to remove everything starting with the first `.`, first note that `sed 's/\..*//'` removes `.` followed by any number of characters from *every line of its input*, not the input as a whole, and you'd need to pass the content of `$i` as input, not as argument. `sed` treats its arguments as file names to read the input from, so:

```
printf '%s\n' "$i" | sed 's/\..*//'
```

For instance. Though to remove everything starting with the first `.` in the whole input, that would rather have to be:

```
printf '%s\n' "$i" | sed '
  :1
  $!{
    # except on the line line, append the next line to the
    # pattern space and loop
    N
    b1
  }
  s/\..*//'
```

Comment: Thanks for the help! I have been looking into this for the whole morning! It is working now! Btw, do you mind to elaborate on `{i%%.*}`? What does the `i%%` referring to?